# What is special about the perl import subroutine?

Tags: perl, package

It took me two hours to track down this error.  I can work around it, but I don't understand it.

If I have a perl module `./lib/My/Foo.pm` that looks like this:

```
package My::Foo;

sub import {print "importing\n"}

1;
```

Then using it calls the `import` subroutine implicitly:

```
$ PERL5LIB=./lib perl -MMy::Foo -e 'print "ok\n"'
importing
ok
```

But if I copy the same module and use it without the colons, the `import` subroutine is **not** called.

```
$ cp lib/My/Foo.pm lib/Foo.pm
$ PERL5LIB=./lib perl -MFoo -e 'print "ok\n"'
ok
```

If I change `import` to something else like `do_import`, the subroutine isn't called.  So I can avoid this behavior.  But in my real use case, I have an `Import` class and with an abstract method `import`, then implement that method in subclasses.  So I *don't* want this `import` method called automatically when `use`ing the parent class.

I looked in `perlootut` and `perlobj` and didn't see any mention of this.

Comment: When you copied the module, did you remove the `My::` from the `package My::Foo` line?

Comment: @stevieb: No, just a straight copy.

Comment: perl loads things based on directory location, so `lib/Foo.pm` requires the package name to be `Foo`. Likewise, `My::Foo` would be `lib/My/Foo.pm`. `Foo` can't be found. Try removing the incorrect portion of the package name (`My::`).

Comment: @stevieb Really?  Because if I try `PERL5LIB=./lib perl -MFoo -e 'print "ok "; My::Foo->import()'` on the command line I get `ok importing`

Comment: Maybe I didn't make my question clear.  I *don't* want `import` to be called implicitly.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Indeed, and I don't mean to sound impetuous by wanting it.  My question was basically, "It seems like I can't use `import` as a subroutine.  Is that right?"  And the answer is "Yes, you can't use `import` as a subroutine."

Comment: you can use import as a subroutine if you are aware of its special nature (the caller can prevent the implicit call; see my answer), but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @SinanÜnür the doc uses "exactly" inexactly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`import()` is a special method name in Perl. Whenever you `use` a module, Perl will look for a subroutine called `import()` inside that module and, if it finds it, it will be run.

This is most often used for [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) cleverness. It means that having a method called `import()` in your module that you don't want to be called as the module is loaded is a **very bad idea**. It will leave you fighting against Perl at every turn.

See [perldoc -f import](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) for pointers to more information:

> **import LIST**
>
> There is no builtin `import` function. It is just an ordinary method (subroutine) *defined (or inherited) by modules that wish to export names* to another module. *The `use` function calls the `import` method for the package used*. See also [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html#use-Module-VERSION-LIST), [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html), and [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html).

The "workaround" you have found is also not a very good idea. You are effectively loading a module called My:Foo from a file called Foo.pm and Perl will get very confused if the filename and package name don't match.

Comment: Thanks also for the explanation and the reference.  My "workaround" is *not* changing the module location.  It was changing the method from `import` to something else like `do_import` (based on these answers, I see now this is really the only way to do it).  I only figured out that `import` was somehow special by moving the module to a nonstandard location.  That part was just poking around to see what changed.

Comment: For completeness' sake, you could also `require` the module instead of `use`ing it, in which case the `import` method will not be executed if I recall correctly. But simply using another name for your method is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: @janh: That sounds dangerous. You're relying on people using your module in the way you ask them too :-)

Comment: Absolutely, and I'd strongly advise against it, but it IS an option, albeit a dangerous one. I'm pretty sure I'd have forgotten that and would change it back to `use` after a few weeks to let the fun begin anew.

Comment: Thank you again.  Since `perldoc -f import` is three sentences long, I went ahead and embedded it.

Answer (score 8):

Seems to me that you're looking at the wrong end of this camel.  Your problem isn't caused by `import` being "special", but rather by not knowing what exactly `use` actually does.  Per [perldoc use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), `use Module` is "exactly equivalent" to

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

When you use `use`, *you are telling Perl to call the Module's `import` method.*  Simple as that.

Of course, Perl being Perl, there probably is some way for your `import` method to figure out whether it's being called as part of a `use` and immediately return if that's the case, but that would just add needless complexity.  Renaming the method to something more descriptive (e.g., `import_file`, `import_record`, etc., depending on what it is that you're actually importing) would be a much better solution.

Comment: You're right; I didn't know that use = require + import.  Thanks for spelling that out so clearly.  I will definitely use a different method.

Answer (score 3):

`import` is special in two ways:

Unless `use` is explicitly given an empty import list (e.g. `use Foo ();`), `import` will be called at compile time as a class method and passed any import list arguments `use` was given.

If `import` is called as a instance or class method (whether implicitly by `use` or explicitly) and no such method exists, an empty list will be returned instead of a `Can't locate object method` error being thrown or AUTOLOAD being called.

If it were implemented today, it would probably be called `IMPORT` instead.

All of the above also applies to `unimport` (but with `no` instead of `use`).

Update: some have linked to the docs where it says what `use` is "exactly equivalent" to and then lies.

It is exactly equivalent to `BEGIN { require Module; Module::->VERSION(...); Module::->import(...) }` except the VERSION call is omitted if no version is specified and the import call is omitted if an explict empty list is given (as the docs later clarify).

(Also note the subtle distinction between Module->import (which calls a Module() function if it exists and then calls the import method on whatever that returns) and Module::->import or 'Module'->import which is a straightforward class method call on the Module class.)

Answer (score 2):

`import` is a reserved keyword. When you `use` a module, its `import` method will be called, see [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html).

I'm afraid you can't change that. Rename your method to something else that isn't a special keyword.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.  I had found that page before, but was confused by the line "There is no builtin import function."  I should have read onward to "The `use` function calls the import method for the package used."

Comment: Pedantically, `import` isn't a reserved keyword, it's just the name of a subroutine. But a subroutine that is treated specially by Perl.